# Anyone having trouble install Control.Pipe?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, ghci, cabal-install

I have the current version of cabal and running `cabal install Pipe` gave me no issues. But I tried these two imports:

```
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Pipe
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
Could not find module `Control.Pipe'
It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

And the same for Proxy.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg list pipes` report back?

Comment: awesome command to know, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have installed [Pipe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Pipe). You probably meant to install [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes).